# Selected Item on BottomNavigationView is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `BottonNavigationView`. Whichever Item is selcted gets hidden. I also added the visible tag, but it still remains the same.
The code for navigation is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_tasks"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/tasks"
        android:title="@string/tasks"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard"
        android:visible="true" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications"
        android:visible="true" />

</menu>
```

The layout file contains :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Here are the screenshots :

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is your primary and accent color?

Comment: Please show custom xml of drawable/tasks which you have used as a icon

Comment: Try changing android:layout_width="0dp" into android:layout_width="wrap_content" in the layout.

Comment: @CodeBullsInc.in navigation or layout? moreover i don't think that might be the problem. because width would be overall, not when selected

Comment: It's visible,you can be able to see if you tilt your screen a little bit. I can see both task & Dashboard. Change the background colour of your bottom navigation bar, then your selected menu will be visible.

Comment: Actually it is in same colour as navigation, so its not visible

Comment: @AshishGupta no. still not visible

Comment: Change colour of your bottom navigation to something dark.

Comment: @AshishGupta oh yes that might be it. let me check

Comment: @AshishGupta thanks done

Comment: change your background color of navigation view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BottomNavigationView` color is white and selected item color is also white try changing background of `BottomNavigationView` by `app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"`

**OR**

If you want white background `BottomNavigationView` then change color of items based on state like this-

Create a drawable name `item_color_state.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--Selected Item Color--> 
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true" />

    <!--Unselected Item Color--> 
    <item android:color="@color/gray" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

In your `BottomNavigationView` add this

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_color_state"
    ...
    />
```

> **Note-** return true in onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: it should be item_color_state, but thanks  in the layout bootonavigationview

Comment: Edited my answer